# Is null value considered in for loop i java?

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    List<Integer> l1= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, null, 3, 4));
    for(Integer l:l1)
    {
        System.out.println(l);
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

The output is coming as -
1
Hello
2
Hello
null
Hello
3
Hello
4
Hello

My question is does loop in java considers null in case of any custom objects as well? Also why it is not thrwoing any null pointer exception? I am new to java, so this might be a silly question.

I was expecting null values will never be considered in any case, as it behave in case of if else condition.

Comment: `why it is not thrwoing any null pointer exception?` Because you're not doing anything with that `null`.

Comment: `My question is does loop in java considers null in case of any custom objects as well?` It loops over __all__ elements of the list. Whether the element is `null` or not doesn't matter.

Comment: To answer your first question, Integer is an object. Custom objects in this situation are treated the same. Next, println will print `"null"` if it reaches a null value. Next, if you want a NPE, then do `System.out.println(l.getClass());`, and you will see your NullPointerException.

Comment: Ok, I understand it now Hovercraft Full Of Eels. Many many thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @tkausl: well, technically, it *could* throw an exception, theoretically. It's not doing so only because this output is the defined behavior of `PrintStream#println` in the JLS.

Comment: To the OP, regarding, "*Also why it is not thrwoing any null pointer exception? I am new to java, so this might be a silly question.*" -- no, it's not a "silly" question, but it probably should be a better *researched* question. If I can teach you one thing and one thing alone here, it is to better search  the site. Please check out [this Google search rubric that I use to search the site for programming language-specific questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+java+println+null+nullpointerexception).

Comment: [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)) of `println()` states: "... This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, ..." and the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) of `valueOf()` says: "if the argument is null, then a string equal to "null"; otherwise, the value of obj.toString() is returned." --> no NullPointerException - use `System.out.println(l.toString())` to get the NPE

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, Thanks a lot for providing wonderful insights regarding this matter.